# "Object required" error 424

Tags: excel, find, offset, vba

I have 2 sheets `List` and `Comments`.
`List` is auto updated from another sheet that imports and formats data

I want to keep track of how often we use each object in sheet `List` by double clicking on the ID cell `(Range("List!$B$6:$B$22"))` but as the data is always changing the ID's move around.
the `Comments` which is a list of all possible ID's and its comments but not the imported values would be a good place to store count data and last used date.

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


If InRange(Target, Range("List!$B$6:$B$22")) Then
    Set c = Worksheets("Comments").Range("$A$2:$A$500").Find(Target.Value)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set c.Offset(0, 1) = c.Offset(0, 1) + 1
            Set c.Offset(0, 2) = Date
    End If
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to **Set**

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$6:$B$22")) Is Nothing Then
    Set c = Worksheets("Comments").Range("$A$2:$A$500").Find(Target.Value)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
             c.Offset(0, 1) = c.Offset(0, 1) + 1
             c.Offset(0, 2) = Date
    End If
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```