# Object Required Error for copy and paste between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel, object

I am new at excel VBA and have learnt all I know through books, trial, forums, and experimentation (in otherwords dont laugh too much at my code).

I wrote this code to copy the values from a range of two (2) contigous cells from a current "client sheet" (this code will initialize through a button placed in many client sheets in the same workbook created through another macro operation).  The copied values will then be pasted to a fixed sheet(2) where a unique value in the row of current sheet matches the unique value in the row in sheet(2), but offset -7 columns from the unique value cell in the Sheet(2) corresponding row.

I am getting a ***Object Required - error 424.*** at the line "**ActiveCell.PasteSpecial.xlValues**"
Please help.  Spend hours and hours.

I have attached the code below

```
Sub UpdateSht2()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As String, d As Range, e As Range

Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set w2 = Sheets(2)
Set d = ActiveCell
Set e = w2.Range("L2:L5000")

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
c = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).value
Cells.Range(d.Offset(0, -1), d).Copy

w2.Activate
w2.Unprotect 
e.Select
e.Find(c, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial.xlValues

w2.Protect 

w1.Activate
d.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Object required" error 424](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083627/object-required-error-424)

Comment: `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial.xlValues` should be `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you...

```
Sub UpdateSht2()

    'Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    'Dim c As String, d As Range, e As Range
    Dim w1 As Worksheet 'Looks its more code, but it reads easy
    Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As Range
    Dim e As Range

    Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'ok
    Set w2 = Sheets(2) 'ok
    Set d = ActiveCell 'ok
    Set e = w2.Range("L2:L5000") 'ok

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate 'Why you want to ACTIVATE, the ACTIVESHEET? It is ok, but this line does nothing.
    c = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 'Store data string into c var.

    '##########################################
    'Cells.Range(d.Offset(0, -1), d).Copy ' Well... some words here...
        '##########################################
        'cells.range([...]).copy it is completly functional, but is important to keep you code
        'clean and easy to read, for you most of all. And then you can use this
        'Range([...]).copy
        'Inside [...]
        'you can put a string with the address of the range you want to use: "A1:D30"
        'You can use the Cells functions:
        'Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(30,4)).copy and this is the same range as "A1:D30"
        'Use cells this way: Cells(Row, Column)
        'This is because Range can read that this object (Cells) is a cell, but if you use a range var type you get an error

        '#########################Fail
        'Sub Fail()
        '    Dim d As Range
        '    Set d = Range("A1")
        '    Range(d).Select
        'End Sub
        '#########################

        '#########################OK
        'Sub Good()
        '    Dim d As Range
        '    Set d = Range("A1")
        '    Range(d.Address).Select 'here you are returning the address of A1, as string
        'End Sub

        '#########################OK
        'Sub Good()
        '    Dim d As Range 'unused
        '    Set d = Range("A1") 'unused
        '    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Select 'The range funct read you want to select A1 of row1 and column1
        '    'Remember using this always need to set it that way
        '    'Cells(),Cells()
        'End Sub

        'And you can use Cells().copy but only with one cell at the time.
        'This is very handy when you need to go across many rows and columns...

        '#########################
        'Sub forExample()
        'Dim i
        'Dim j
        '
        'For i = 1 To 30
        '    For j = 1 To 10
        '        Cells(i, j).Value = "R: " & i & "C: " & j
        '    Next j
        'Next i
        'End Sub
        '######################### Result
        'R: 1C: 1    R: 1C: 2    R: 1C: 3
        'R: 2C: 1    R: 2C: 2    R: 2C: 3
        'R: 3C: 1    R: 3C: 2    R: 3C: 3
        'R: 4C: 1    R: 4C: 2    R: 4C: 3....
        'Well returning to your code...
        'Cells.Range(d.Offset(0, -1), d).Copy you are wrong because you put an object that range can't use...

    'The right one:
    d.Offset(0, -1).Copy 'here copy just one cell!

    'Other example:
    Dim r1
    Dim c1
    Dim r2
    Dim c2

    r1 = d.Offset(0, -1).Row 'this is equal as below:
    r1 = d.Row 'here just take the row integer of d range
    c1 = d.Offset(0, -1).Column 'Here just take the column integer of d range.

    'the other cells...
    r2 = d.Row
    c2 = d.Column

    Range(Cells(r1, c1), Cells(r2, c2)).Copy 'here you copy a range of cells defined by the offset in r1 and c1
    'End of example

    w2.Activate
    w2.Unprotect
    e.Select

    '####Your code
    e.Find(c, LookIn:=xlValues).Select 'this is ok... but here is my code...
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Activate
    'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial.xlValues ' wrong
    'Heres is the answer of you question...!
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'ok

    '####My code
    'Dim f As Range 'always put declarations of vars above.
    'Set f = e.Find(c, LookIn:=xlValues)
    'f.Offset(0, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    w2.Protect

    w1.Activate
    d.Select
    'TIP: Never forget the indentation, it will be easy to read if you used.
    'i know would be hard, but always is better to use name variables to say more about the data or object
    'you store inside...
    'instead of "c" you can use a word(s) to tell you more about the stored data.
    'But this is just my coding style, may be you are good with that... Peace!
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  The coding and instructions were helpful... as I said I learned by forums and all the letters instead of discriptive handles were using code snipbets from research, and activating active sheets was from trying to activate and relate the missing "object." that had me stumped.  However, your code pasted the values one row above the destination when using "f As range" paste as opposed to my "Active Cell" paste.  I don't know why...logically setting f as referencing what I had as "ActivecCell should do the same thing.

Comment: Hi, because in my code i got an error `f.Offset(0, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` but the seven positive and your code used negative `f.Offset(0, -7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`, sorry, my mistake!. I learned as you did... just with books and forums... Never give up!!! And tellme if the answer is ok!

Comment: I did catch the -7 error, and the reason why the row was one row up, was I forgot to add to your code the reference of the "c" lookfor, so it choose a row with a null value which was happened in my test to be the row above.  Cheers.  Your code worked great and very clean and I learned much. Thanks!